# Revealing a glyphicon link upon hovering over text

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been running into a problem with having a glyphicon link show up when hovering over text.

I have this div in my html.

```
<div class="editable container">
<h1>File Name: filename<a href="#"><span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></h1>
</div>
```

With this CSS and JS.
CSS:

```
.editable span.pencil{
float: right;
}

.editable h1 .pencil{
display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.editable h1').hover(function(){

$(this).children('span.pencil').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
    },function(){  

$(this).children('span.pencil').css({'display' : 'none'});
    });
});
```

The idea is that when I hover over the text "File Name: filename" a pencil glyphicon should appear to the far right in the container (which should be a link).

But I've been running into this problem where this doesn't work, but if I remove the 'a' tags it'll work. But so far the only solution I've found to get the link to work is to change
$('.editable h1')
to
$('.editable a')
while adding some sort of text between the 'a' tags. But then I have to hover over the that text vs. the rest of h1.

I'd like to have the glyphicon show up as a link by highlighting over h1. But I'm not entirely sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! You were almost there. Actually this can be achieved using only pure CSS even without jQuery. Just edit your first part of CSS to the following:

```
.editable h1:hover .pencil {
    float: right;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! If I was to do this in jQuery, what was I missing?

Comment: @JonathanHuang your jQuery is also almost fine :) Just change `children` to `find`. Check the docs for the difference.